# sudo npm install -g mocha not working

Tags: npm, mocha.js

I am just running a basic mocha install command and its throwing the error in the mac terminal, Please suggest seeing the logs what can i do to get this running, Really appreciate the help.

```
AUK03154:~ itrmg$ sudo npm install –g mocha
Password:
npm ERR! 404 404 Not Found: %E2%80%93g
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 '%E2%80%93g' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, or http url, or git url.

npm ERR! System Darwin 13.1.0
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "–g" "mocha"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/itrmg
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.29
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.14
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/itrmg/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Thanks
Deepesh

Answer (score 3):

If you decode `%E2%80%93g`, you get `-g`. Something is wrong with the `-` character in `-g`. I copied the `–` character from your question to get its character code:

```
'–'.charCodeAt(0)
8211
```

Then I typed the dash myself:

```
'-'.charCodeAt(0)
45
```

As you can see your dash has a different character code. If you copy this command, it should work:

```
npm install -g mocha
```

Answer (score 0):

If you did a copy-paste of that command from another webpage/text-editor, there are some unwanted characters which get copied. Try typing the same command manually, the error should go away.